# Adding a jQuery Click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following div in a page (I can not modify).

```
   <div id=":0.control">Click me</div>
```

Now I want to add a jQuery Click handler

```
$("#:0.control").click(function () {
         alert('Clicked');
     }
 );
```

Above gives error. Any solution??

Comment: your id is invalid, but if you cannot change the markup you have to find that div in some other way... you may need to post the whole html code

Comment: Weird name, I'm not sure the name is even valid. Try to name it control0 may be

Comment: I am adding an external google widget (an external .js). This id is in the code. I want to hook the div to perform my own task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
$("#:0.control")
```

try

```
$('div[id="\\:0\\.control"]')
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Yt6jU/1/)**

or

```
$("#\\:0\\.control") // better that previous one
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Yt6jU/2/)**

Comment: Talk about code maintenance! Good answer but I feel sorry for those who'll stumble upon this when reading his code.

Answer (score 3):

You can escape special characters in selectors:

```
$("#\\:0\\.control").click(function () {
     alert('Clicked');
});​
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Yt6jU/).

Note that unless you are using the HTML5 doctype, your ID is invalid. Also note that escaping the special characters is [significantly faster](http://jsperf.com/jq-escaped-vs-attr) than using an attribute selector as in another answer:

[image]

The reason for this is that the browser can take advantage of the speed of `getElementById`, rather than having to rely on `querySelector` or Sizzle.

Answer (score 1):

This is ugly,but it works:

```
$(document.getElementById(":0.control"))
```

In cases, when `id` is stored in variable, you have to use:

```
var id = ":0.control";
$(document.getElementById(id))
```

Otherwise, when you want to use pure `jQuery`, you need to add additional slashes.

*More complex example:*

```
var idArray = [":bla-bla","bla[]","commonId"];
$.each( idArray, function(i,id){
    $(document.getElementById(id)) //do some stuff
    //Otherwise, when using pure jQuery, we need to add slashes before ':','[',']' characters 
});
```